# Не удается подключить заголовочный файл

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Использую Visual Studio 2013, в проекте добавил в папку заголовочных файлов нужный файл с расширением ".h" (randomc.h).
Затем в исходном коде пишу #include "randomc.h"
но он не находит файл: не удается открыть источник файл "randomc.h"
Аналогично при подключении .cpp-файлов.
Эти файлы уже даже положил в директорию с проектом, все равно то же самое.

Comment: А какая у вас структура каталогов? (И кстати, подключать .cpp файлы скорее всего ошибка.)

Comment: /VisualStudio2013/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectName/Release - сюда я кладу свои файлы (по умолчанию, вроде, отсюда он берет).
Вдобавок к этому я подключаю в самом VS заголовочный файл и указываю путь к нему.

Comment: По умолчанию *.h берутся из того же каталога, где лежит файл проекта. Каталоги Release/Debug - для результатов сборки.

Comment: А *.с/*.cpp у вас лежат в том же каталоге, что и файл проекта?

Comment: Каким образом вы копировали заголовочный файл в "папку заголовочных файлов"? Не перетаскиванием файла в саму студию? Там ещё есть фильтры Header Files и Source Files. И если перетащить  так файл, то он останется в исходной папке, а в проекте будет только ссылка на него. В папке "/VisualStudio2013/Projects/ProjectName/..." через проводник нужные файлы видны?

Comment: Неверно выразился. Указывал ссылку на них в этих самых фильтрах (разве так называется?..) Header Files.

Answer (score 5):

В свойствах проекта в параметре Additional Include Directories необходимо указать путь ко всем папкам (отличным от корневой папки проекта и стандартной библиотеки), где лежать *.h

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, теперь заработало (указал путь к другой папке). Почему не работает автоматически, когда файлы лежат в директории с проектом - не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас написано #include "randomc.h", то randomc.h должен быть в том же каталоге, что и файл, в котором это написано. Это если не рассматривать дополнительные каталоги для include.

Comment: Туда тоже уже положил, не работает.

Comment: Значит вы что-то делаете не так, а что именно - не пишете :-)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не ошибаться, лучше просто использовать "  " , отличие в том, что таким образом сначала идет поиск в директории, где находится файл , а затем уже там , где обычно ищется при <>

Answer (score -2):

`#include "./randomc.h"`

Если файл в корне

Comment: @Duoxx вполне похоже на ответ.